# How to have one line per row in a cellTable?

Tags: gwt

I am using a CellTable on a ScrollPanel in GWT. My table has two columns and I want to give 10% and 90% of the width each. This is fine.

The problem is that I want to have one line of text per row in the table. That is if the content of one cell is too large to be showed in one line, I want to have either a horizontal scrolling bar or just truncate the text to fit it in one line.

Here is an extract of my code:

```
cellTable.addColumn(column1);
cellTable.addColumn(column2);
cellTable.setWidth("100%", true);
cellTable.setColumnWidth(column1, 10.0, Unit.PCT);
cellTable.setColumnWidth(column2, 90.0, Unit.PCT);
```

I also tried to use:

```
cellTable.setTableLayoutFixed(true);
```

but it doesn't change the layout.

Thanks a lot for your comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CSS property "white-space: nowrap"

[More info](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)

Comment: Thanks! The "white-space: nowrap" property and value make the trick.

Comment: You might want to tell folks where to specify this style.  It's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to play with the `word-wrap`, `overflow` and possibly `text-overflow` CSS properties.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried these CSS properties (corresponding to the cellTable widget) but it doesn't seem to change anything. In fact, other simple CSS properties, like font-size, don't seem to be working either. Any clue about what I can be doing wrong?

Comment: You'll have to apply them to the table cells (`td` DOM elements) or maybe even deeper (the `div` inside the `td` that corresponds to the `Cell` being rendered). I'm sorry, I have tried it myself, so I can't tell exactly.